# Finding expectation from joint distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, expected-value

Suppose that $P(X=i,Y=j)=c(i+j)$ for non-negative integers $i$ and $j$ with $i+j \leq 3$; otherwise, the probability is zero.

(f) Compute $E[XY]$

(g) Compute $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$

(h) Compute $E[X+Y]$

only parts f,g,h below

I've done the previous parts a to e but am confused with the parts related to mean E

I have attached a picture of my work for parts a to e for reference

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math.

Answer (score 0):

You've miscalculated $c$, it should be $1/20$, the points with non-zero probability mass are $$\mathcal{S}=\{(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(3,0)\}$$
Anyway, this won't change the calculation method of (f-h). Since you have the marginals, and they're same for $X,Y$ due to symmetry, we have $E[X]=E[Y]$:
$$E[X]=\sum_{i=0}^3 iP(X=i)$$
For (h), we'll use the linearity of expectation: $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]=2E[X]$. For (f), we need a double summation since it's a joint statistic:
$$E[XY]=\sum_{i+j\leq 3}ijP(X=i,Y=j)=P(X=1,Y=1)+2P(X=2,Y=1)\ ...$$